# c# Newtonsoft : get json token with name containing special character

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have some Json files containing special character like this :

```
{
  "someProperties" : "someValues",
  "$ROOT_QUERY.searchResults({\"path\":\"/some/url\"}).features": 
  {
    "propertyOtherA": "valueA",
    "propertyOtherB": "null",
  },
  "$ROOT_QUERY.searchResults({\"path\":\"/some/url\"}).otherText": 
  {
    "propertyOtherA": "valueA",
    "propertyOtherB": "null",
  }
}
```

How can I set the token path to get it ?
When I try the standard path, I get a Unexpected character exception

```
string path = "$ROOT_QUERY.searchResults({\\\"path\\\":\\\"" + request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery + "\\\"})";
var token = jObject.SelectToken("$." + path + ".features");
```

I also tried to replace string in Json, but the string.Contains method is not returning true, whereas it works fine in notepad.
I also tried simple Regex, but i've not succed to make it work.
My last idea is atomic Regex, but before entering to this hell, I'm trying to ask you if I can any chance to get it with a simplier way.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape `path` using `'[]'` - note that `.features` should also be included:

```txt
var path = "['$ROOT_QUERY.searchResults({\"path\":\"" + request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery + "\"}).features']";
var token = jObject.SelectToken("$." + path);
Console.WriteLine(token);
```

You need to escape this entire path, because you have multiple "reserved" characters there: `$`, `.`, `()` (see [this non-oficial documentation](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2)). See other escaping examples [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenEscaped.htm).

[demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vjHnFK).

Comment: Works great ! And the documentation is very interesting. Thank you very much